# How to use Jquery to print each value from an XML file?

Tags: jquery, xml

Anyone know how to go through an XML file using Jquery and print the tag names and text values from only the tags that have a text value in them?

Example, html that outputs like:

```
id: 00130000004EQCpAAO
updated: 2011-08-16 19:40:51
account_type: Vendor Other
active: 1
someprop_d: 0
```

that comes from XML like:

```
<accounts>
    <id>00130000004EQCpAAO</id>
    <updated>2011-08-16 19:40:51</updated>
    <account_type>Vendor Other</account_type>
    <someprop_a/>
    <active_c>1</active_c>
    <someprob_b/>
    <someprop_c/>
    <someprop_d>0</someprop_d>
</accounts>
```

The Jquery:

```
var mystr = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/js/data_account.xml',
    async: false,
    data: {
        key: "value"
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var xml = $(data)
        //var $accountid = xml.find("id").text();
        // do something relevant here
        //return something;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error: call failed");
    }
});
$('parentElement').append(mystr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the value of the `.nodeName` property to get the tag name and use `.text()` to get the text content.  Eg:

```
var idNode = xml.find("id");
var nodeName = idNode[0].nodeName;
var nodeText = idNode.text();
```

You can iterate the xml and get the output you want:

```
xml.find("accounts > *").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text) {
        $("#xmlOutput").append($("<div>").text(this.nodeName + ": " + text));
    }
});
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/KYWCK/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the contents method on jquery and check the nodetype for text nodes. You can learn about the contents method here: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Also the nodeType definitions can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Something like:

```
var textNodes = $(data).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('accounts').each(function(){
  var $accountid =  $(this).find('id').text();
  alert($accountid);
});
```